# determining location of deprecation warning on Ember.js

Tags: debugging, ember.js

I upgraded to Ember 1.18 and I'm getting:

```
DEPRECATION: Using currentWhen with {{link-to}} is deprecated in favor of `current-when`.
        at Ember.LinkView.EmberComponent.extend.init (http://example.com:8000/static/assets/vendor.js:33811:15)
        at apply (http://example.com:8000/static/assets/vendor.js:32885:32)
        at superWrapper [as init] (http://example.com:8000/static/assets/vendor.js:32459:15)
        at apply (http://example.com:8000/static/assets/vendor.js:32885:32)
        at new Class (http://example.com:8000/static/assets/vendor.js:47485:9)
        at Function.Mixin.create.create (http://example.com:8000/static/assets/vendor.js:47943:16)
        at CoreView.extend.createChildView (http://example.com:8000/static/assets/vendor.js:56278:23)
        at Object.merge.appendChild (http://example.com:8000/static/assets/vendor.js:54369:26)
        at CoreView.extend.appendChild (http://example.com:8000/static/assets/vendor.js:56161:34)
```

None of the traceback is my code, and I'm mainly using `{link-to-animated}` (without `currentWhen` explicitly).

How can I figure out where to find the problematic code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deprecation notice isn't showing a traceback to your code because the issue isn't in your code. :) Take a look at [ember-animated-outlet.js](https://github.com/billysbilling/ember-animated-outlet/blob/0fd9b9f44fbd6745af78a47902c3957c7885fe2c/dist/ember-animated-outlet.js#L306) and you'll see that `currentWhen` is used internally.

There's a few dirty tricks to silence deprecation warnings, but I would suggest just submitting a pull-request to the repo to have it changed. It should be a fairly easy fix.

EDIT: It seems there's [already a pull request for that](https://github.com/billysbilling/ember-animated-outlet/pull/57), but it hasn't been merged yet. So about those dirty tricks... If you're bugged by the deprecation warning, you can always override `Ember.deprecate`. Put the following somewhere before your app code is run (maybe in a vendor script):

```
var oldDeprecate = Ember.deprecate;
Ember.deprecate = function(message) {
    if (message.indexOf('currentWhen') >= 0) {
        return;
    }

    return oldDeprecate.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I got to that point in the code, but my fix was incorrect...
Is there a way I could figure out it is because of ember-animated other than using my head? (a more methodical way - that what my original question was for)

Comment: The only better way I know of would be to use the Ember inspector's new deprecation feature. However, that's going to give you the same stack trace you see in the console. If the deprecation is in your code, it'll be pretty easy to spot in the stack trace. Unfortunately, if the issue is in library code, there aren't any better ways than just checking the stack trace locations, searching the file, and thinking critically.

Comment: thanks. By the way - a weird thing... after fixing the code, I still get the warning. And putting a breakpoint on the line in the chrome debugger isn't getting exexuted. Any ideas WTF?

Comment: It's likely that the old version of the `deprecate` function is being cached in a closure somewhere. (Ember-CLI works a bit differently than my setup.) It honestly might be too difficult to disable the warning. Maybe just fork the original repo, change the offending code, then point your `bower.json` at your repo for it. (I've done that in the past.)